# Having trouble clicking object in Hololens2, using Aframe

Tags: aframe, webxr

I'm trying to build an app with hololens2 using aframe but i'm having trouble clicking the object with laser-controls in ar mode.
With the codes below, I can click the object like few seconds no matter how many times i click it, it works but after few seconds, it stops working.
However, here in this example, [https://glitch.com/~aframe-building-ui](https://glitch.com/%7Eaframe-building-ui) it works fine and it is also using laser-controls.
can anyone tell me what could be the problem?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.3.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script>
           AFRAME.registerComponent('click', {
            dependencies: ['material'],
            init: function () {
              var btn = document.querySelector("#clickbtn");
              var isClick = false;
              btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {  
                  if(isClick == false){
                    btn.setAttribute('material', 'color', 'tomato');
                    isClick = true;
                  } 
                  else{
                    btn.setAttribute('material', 'color', 'white');
                    isClick = false;
                  }                
              });
            }
          });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene
      id="a_scene"  
      background="color: #837E7C"
      cursor="rayOrigin: mouse; fuse: false" 
      raycaster="objects: .raycastable">    
      <a-camera>
        <a-box 
          click
          position="-1.7 -0.2 -8"
          id="clickbtn"
          material="color: white; opacity:1"
          width="0.5" 
          height="0.5" 
          depth="0.05" 
          animation__scale="property: scale; to: 2 2 2; dur: 200; startEvents: mouseenter"
          animation__scale_reverse="property: scale; to: 1 1 1; dur: 200; startEvents: mouseleave"
          class="raycastable">
        </a-box>
      </a-camera>

      <a-entity id="mouseCursor" cursor raycaster="objects: .raycastable"></a-entity>
      <a-entity id="leftHand" laser-controls="hand: left" raycaster="objects: .raycastable"></a-entity>
      <a-entity id="rightHand" laser-controls="hand: right" raycaster="objects: .raycastable"></a-entity>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you change the version from 1.3.0 to 1.0.4 then at least clicking object problem is fixed.

```
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.4/aframe.min.js"></script>
```